# Multiple ocsp responder url support in java non progrmatically

Tags: url, ocsp

Any way to add multiple ocsp responder url's in java. I know that we can add one ocsp responder url in java but not sure in latest jdk supports multiple ocsp responder url's non progrmatically by setting in java.security file. Please let me know if it supported.

Thanks in Advance.